# Using Regular Expressions to replace a select instance of a character

Tags: java, regex

First and foremost, this is not a homework/school question. This is something I needed for a personal project and was able to generalize the problem using simple characters as follows:

Create a regular expression which can be used in the java string replaceAll function for an input string aaabaabaa (or similar) and converts each a to A, UNLESS it is preceded by a b. So the expected output is AAAbaAbaA. I've been trying this for at least 2 hours now... The best I could come up with was:

```
replaceAll("^a|([^b])a", "$1A");
```

This fails on aaa, where the return value is AaA

I'm trying to say "Any 'a' without a 'b' before it should be an A. Any ideas for a RegEx novice? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a negative lookbehind:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!b)a", "A");
```

This will match any `a` *not* immediately preceded by a `b`.

Comment: Yep, that's the functionality I was missing. I didn't know about lookaheads or look behinds. It's been a few years since I worked with regex and Im not sure I ever used those! But thanks very much!